# How do I connect to a local postgres database without password from a script within Apache

Tags: python, apache, postgresql, cgi

I have a Python script that should load some data into postgres when a POST request is sent to Apache Webserver. In the script a system user (dbuser) is used to connect to the database (which works fine with psql). The script however cannot connect when it is executed within Apache, returning the following error:

```
Peer authentication failed for user dbuser
```

Is there a way to allow the script to connect without providing it the user password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I've found uses ident authentication with user maps.

The first thing to notice is that, although an username is provided in the script, when connecting via Apache, that user is used for peer authentication (which fails, requiring a password). However, the system user requesting access to postgresql is the one running Apache (namely www-data), thus enabling us to configure an user map, allowing is to authenticate to the server as another system user (thus leveraging ident authentication). Here follows the configuration files content:

In pg_ident.conf we configure the user map:

```
# MAPNAME      SYSTEM-USERNAME         PG-USERNAME
web            www-data                dbuser
web            dbuser                  dbuser
```

In pg_hba.conf we add the map as an option to the local peer authentication:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
# TYPE  DATABASE     USER    ADDRESS     METHOD
local   all          all                 peer map=web
```

After reloading the server, the script can access the database as if it was executed directly the the user "dbuser", without the need for a password.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the below command, it will enable apache to connect to database:

> setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1

Comment: Thanks but I do not use SELinux on the server and the connection is already working. It is the database that does not accept a passwordless auth over network.